# Nearest distance between one marker and polyline defined by two ends

Tags: javascript

I developed a web application using javascript language in order to manipulate a leaflet map and I find myself stuck on knowing how I can calculate the shortest distance (the orthogonal projection) between a marker given by latlng and a polyline constructed by two other given markers. I thought about adding the coordinates of all the points that are inside the polyline and making a comparison between the distances of these points and the starting marker but I cannot make the desired add loop.
Here is a portion[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX1Kx.jpg) of my code:

```js
var userLocation = new L.LatLng(36.69666789, 8.625412236);
    var userLocation1 = new L.LatLng(36.18, 9.62);
    var userLocation2 = new L.LatLng(37.18, 9.62);
    var markerr = new L.Marker(userLocation);
    var markerr1 = new L.Marker(userLocation1);
    var markerr2 = new L.Marker(userLocation2);
    map.addLayer(markerr);map.addLayer(markerr1);map.addLayer(markerr2);
    var latlngs = [[36.18, 9.62],[37.18, 9.62]];
    latlngs.push([36.69666789, 9.62]);
    var polygline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
                function pointsArray(itemms) {
                var pointsArray = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < itemms.length; i++) {
                    var item = itemms[i];
                    pointsArray.push(new L.LatLng(item[0],item[1]));
                }
                return pointsArray;
            }
            
    var trajet = new L.Polyline(pointsArray(latlngs));
    map.fitBounds([
        [36.18, 9.62],      
        [37.18, 9.62]
    ]);
    alert(getNearestPointToPolyline(markerr, trajet));
//  alert(getLatLngPt2AndCreateMarker(36.69666789, 8.625412236,1.5708,88.67431079733398));
    function getNearestPointToPolyline (marker, polyline) {
      var nearestKey,
          nearestDistance,
          markerLatLng = marker.getLatLng(),
          polylineLatLngs = polyline.getLatLngs()
      for (i = 0; i < polylineLatLngs.length; i++) {
        var distance = markerLatLng.distanceTo(polylineLatLngs[i]) //distance en mètres
        if (!nearestDistance || nearestDistance > distance) {
          nearestKey = i
          nearestDistance = distance
        }
      }
      return nearestKey+' and distance is: '+nearestDistance
    }
    
    function getLatLngPt2AndCreateMarker(lat0,lon0,brng,d) {
          var R = 6378.1; // Radius of the earth in km
          var lat1 = deg2rad(lat0);
          var lon1 = deg2rad(lon0);
          var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d/R) + Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng));
          var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));
          lat2 = rad2deg(lat2);
          lon2 = rad2deg(lon2);
            var use = new L.LatLng(lat2, lon2);
            var mar = new L.Marker(use);
            map.addLayer(mar);        
          return lat2 + ' AND ' + lon2;       
        }
```

Comment: Run code snippet -> `Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined`. Please fix the code

Comment: This article (distance-between-a-point-and-a-line) can help you [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry-home/analytic-geometry-topic/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line/v/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to compare all points on polyline to your point. Remembering that nearest distance from point to a line should be perpendicular to that line. In order to describe it as a line function in cartesian coordinates, you can use below;

```
            double lat1 = currentLine.get(0).latitude;
            double lon1 = currentLine.get(0).longitude;
            double lat2 = currentLine.get(1).latitude;
            double lon2 = currentLine.get(1).longitude;
            double lat3 = CoorLatFixed;
            double lon3 = CoorLongFixed;


            double slope = (lon1-lon2)/(lat1-lat2);
            double b = (lon1)-(slope*lat1);


            double y = Math.sin(lon3 - lon1) * Math.cos(lat3);
            double x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat3) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat3) * Math.cos(lat3 - lat1);
            double bearing1 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
            bearing1 = 360 - ((bearing1 + 360) % 360);

            double y2 = Math.sin(lon2 - lon1) * Math.cos(lat2);
            double x2 = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(lat2 - lat1);
            double bearing2 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y2, x2));
            bearing2 = 360 - ((bearing2 + 360) % 360);

            double lat1Rads = Math.toRadians(lat1);
            double lat3Rads = Math.toRadians(lat3);
            double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon3 - lon1);

            double distanceAC = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1Rads) * Math.sin(lat3Rads)+Math.cos(lat1Rads)*Math.cos(lat3Rads)*Math.cos(dLon)) * 6371;
            double min_distance = Math.abs(Math.asin(Math.sin(distanceAC/6371)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(bearing1)-Math.toRadians(bearing2))) * 6371)*1000;
```

lat1,lon1 lat2,lon2 are variables stands for two endpoints of polyline. lat3,lon3 is the point.